# std::map: is find(key)->second faster than the [] operator?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

```
std::map<long, double> x;
x[5] = 1.2;

double y = x[5];
double z = x.find(5)->second;
```

Will one of these 2 assignments execute faster than the other? (supposing that the requested key is always present in the map) Is there any overhead associated with the dereferencing of the iterator when doing `x.find(5)->second` ?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the replies. In my particular function, now that I know it is not slower, I will probably go with `x.find(5)->second` as I need to mark my function `const` (the map is a member variable) and the `[]` operator obviously does not allow that (as it potentially modifies the map is a key is missing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Took this straight from `<map>`:

```
mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& _Keyval)
    {   // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped
    iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);
    if (_Where == this->end()
        || this->comp(_Keyval, this->_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
        _Where = this->insert(_Where,
            value_type(_Keyval, mapped_type()));
    return ((*_Where).second);
    }

iterator find(const key_type& _Keyval)
    {   // find an element in mutable sequence that matches _Keyval
    iterator _Where = lower_bound(_Keyval);
    return (_Where == end()
        || _DEBUG_LT_PRED(this->comp,
            _Keyval, _Key(_Where._Mynode()))
                ? end() : _Where);
    }
```

It looks about the same. Should there be any difference between:

```
iterator _Where = this->lower_bound(_Keyval);
return ((*_Where).second);
```

and

```
iterator i = x.find(5);
double d = (*i).second;
```

I wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 12):

This doesn't answer your question, but I would point out some problem with the way you're using `find`.

```
double y = x[5];
double z = x.find(5)->second;
```

I cannot comment on which is faster. But I can surely say that the first approach is safe!

What if the map doesn't contain the given key?

In the first approach, it will **create** a new `pair` with the given *key*, and initialize the *value* with default value of `double` (which is zero), and return it.

But the second aproach? `find` will return `map::end` if the specified key is not found in the container, and you're dereferencing it. Program crash!

The correct way to use `find` is:

```
std::map<long, double>::iterator it;    
if ( (it = x.find(key)) != x.end() )
{
    double value = it->second;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you (in fact I gave you +1), but one thought is that it might be subjective which of the failure condition results is better. Maybe you don't want to silently create new values in the map and would rather deal with an exception/compare to `map::end`/whatever. It depends on your use case.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can think of a couple of reasons somebody might have.  (1) In this case, the questioner did say to assume that the key would be present.  (2) The question is on which is faster, not which is "safer".  (3) The case of failing silently is not necessarily "safer" than failing spectacularly.  This is how missiles get accidentally launched.

Comment: @Marlon: I didn't say it answer the question. I was explaining the problem with the code snippet.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you did ignore the part of my question that says "supposing that the requested key is always present in the map" (I know for sure the keys are there, but this is called a huge number of times in a loop which is why it needs to be efficient). I was not asking what happens if it is not there (I know that difference already), just which is faster.

Comment: oops, didn't see all those comments before posting mine :)

Comment: @Nawaz: The answer you gave is a side answer and not what PO wants. As for mentioning which is safer, depending on the scenario, one may not want a new entry to be made if key not found. In that case, find is the right(hence safe for this case) option.

Comment: @Laurent: I see. I think Marlon's post pretty much answer your question. The performance is almost same!

Answer (score 2):

The first assignment using `operator[]` will have to perform the same dereference to retrieve the value that is explicit in `find()->second`. You can profile to be sure but the performance should be close enough that you should use the form that is clearest in your code.